# inner join select only one row from second table base on IF-THEN-ELSE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a users table. Each record has one or more prices and date and state in payments table. I'm just going to show by this priority :

```
 priority 1 => green (with older date)
 priority 2 => green (with new date)
 priority 3 => yellow (with older date if amount>1000)
```

users table

```
╔════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║  name        ║
╠════╬══════════════║
║  1 ║ Jeff_1       ║
║  2 ║ Jeff_2       ║
║  3 ║ Jeff_3       ║
╚════╩══════════════╝
```

payments table

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╗
║ user_id  state  price    date     ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1       green   5000   2019-10-14 ║
║ 1       green   3500   2019-10-11 ║
║ 1       yellow  1000   2019-10-09 ║
║ 2       yellow  50     2019-10-06 ║
║ 2       yellow  4000   2019-10-25 ║
║ 3       yellow  45900  2019-10-02 ║
║ 3       yellow  4000   2019-10-29 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

amount => 1000

What I want:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╗
║ user_id  state  price    date     ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1       green   3500   2019-10-11 ║
║ 2       yellow  4000   2019-10-25 ║
║ 3       yellow  45900  2019-10-02 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Is this question for MySQL or Oracle database as they are different products (although both are owned by the Oracle Corporation).

Comment: Don't use unrelated tags for your question. I removed Mysql since one of your comments states that you use Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                order by (case when state = 'green' then 1 else 2 end),
                                         date asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from payments p
      where state = 'green' or
            (state = 'yellow' and amount > 1000)
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

This assumes that you only want these three priorities.  That is, if no rows match, you don't want the user.

Comment: get error from this point => order by (state = 'green') desc   in sql oracle developer  =>    select delegation,state, row_number() over (partition by sso_id  order by (state = 'green') desc, created_at asc) as tl
  from states where state = 'green' or (state = 'yellow' and delegation > 1000)

Comment: @behzadomidi . . . I used MySQL syntax, because the question was tagged MySQL.

Comment: answer in oracle=> select state,date, row_number() over (partition by user_id  order by   case 
       when state = 'green' then 1
       when state = 'yellow' then 2 
       else 3
    end, date asc) as tl
  from payments where state = 'green' or (state = 'yellow' and delegation > 1000)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to return a result of 3 queries, each of them getting records with a given priority, so

```
(select ..., 1 as priority from ...
union all
select ..., 2 as priority from ...
union all
select ..., 3 as priority from ...)
order by priority
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use analytical function as following.

```
select t.*
from 
  (select t.*,
    row_number() 
      over (partition by user_id 
        order by state, case when state= 'yellow' and price >1000 then 1 end desc, date) as rn
    from payments t
   where state = 'green' or
    (state = 'yellow' and amount > 1000) 
  )t
where rn = 1;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

Use the following script:

```
select u.user_id, payment.state, payment.price, payment.date 
from users u
outer apply(select top 1 * from payments p 
            where p.user_id = u.user_id
            and (p.state = 'green' or (p.state = 'yellow' and p.price > 1000))
            order by p.date)payment
```

Comment: @MT0 You're right, I updated my answer as expected.

Comment: Still not sure it is right as the `ORDER BY` will give the row with the highest date regardless of priority. It should `ORDER BY` green then yellow state first and then lowest (not highest) date second.

Comment: @MT0 I checked for green state firstly for giving it the higher priority, if there's no green, then yellow ones with price condition are retrieved.

Comment: No, you haven't [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5db03039a497c657dddf494c9a54fccf) has an extra row of data and should return `green` for `id` of 1 but returns a `yellow` row. Also, neither MySQL or Oracle supports the `TOP` syntax and MySQL doesn't support `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: If you want an Oracle solution (for Oracle 12c or later as that is the version that supports `OUTER APPLY` and `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`) then [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=db71d1a5582b5dfa36bc426ce7a2558e)